# Permissions on remote server problem

Tags: 7, users

I have this error message:

```
The specified file temporary://fileYU5WGQ could not be copied, because the destination directory is not properly configured. This may be caused by a problem with file or directory permissions. More information is available in the system log.
```

I know it's a folder permission problem. But I can't figure out which folder is the cause.

In **sites/default/files** I have these three folders, all of them with permission set to **777**:

tmp

temp

temporary

Then I don't know where is the problem??
I attached a image capture of the sistem file setting:
[image: capture]

Comment: do you have any sub-folder within this folders?

Comment: no folders inside temp

Comment: do you transfer your drupal from another server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check what user is the owner of each of your folders in question ?
Use chown username:groupname to change owner/group of a folder.

Comment: You hit the point. It is a Owner a Group problem. When drupal create a folder in the remote folder it get Owner: 20003 y Group: 20003 which are Apache settings. How do I tell Drupal to give FTP protocol to the created folders, I mean Owner: 30050 y Group: 30049?

Comment: You cannot change folder permissions/ownership directly in drupal unless you use a module like [Take Control](http://drupal.org/project/take_control) without php code.

The best is to change folder permissions in unix/linux shell or via CPanel, DirectAdmin or ask your host provider.

In shell you use command: chown 30050:30049 foldername

You can also try to change using your ftp client or directly via php commands, for example:

<?php
$file_name = "your_filename.php";
$path = "/your_folderpath/" . $file_name;
$user_name = "your_username";

chmod($path, 0777);
chown($path, $user_name);
?>

Comment: thanks, I guess I need to go deeper in this since I´m having lots of permissions issues.